# if else condition in jquery ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have one Ajax function which is running properly.but i want when my Ajax response is

```
<h3>No Couriers found near by you.please select another location</h3>
```

i want to display some error message else i want to display another map div in else condition.
but every time when i hit Ajax only else condition is working..but when i alert response and see the output it shows this message when

```
<h3>No Couriers found near by you.please select another location</h3>
```

but still it not comes in if condition..can anyone help me to do this....

```
<script>
$('#weight0,#weight1,#weight2,#weight3').click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
     if($(this).is(":checked")) { 
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "Orders","action" => "searchCourier")); ?>',
          data: {
              frmlat: $("#PoolLatitude").val(),
              frmlong: $("#PoolLongitude").val(),
              mylocation: $("#PoolLocation").val()
          },
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(response) {  
          alert(response);
            if(response =="<h3>No Couriers found near by you.please select another location</h3>"){
              alert(thanks);
            } else {
                $('#map_canvas').css('display', 'none');//used to hide map after ajax success response.
                $("#load_map").html(response); 
            }
          }, 
          complete: function() {
              $('.spinicon').hide();
          }
        });
    } else {
            $("#secretcode").val("");
        }    
});
</script>
```

Comment: because this string `<h3>No Couriers found near by you.please select another location</h3>` is not equal to `No Couriers found near by you.please select another location`

Comment: its better to use status in response 1 for success, 0 for failrure, and who knows where u define `thanks` `alert(thanks);` maybe u are looking for `alert("thanks");`

Comment: With issues like this you could check string length to see if what you are comparing is exactly what you think you are comparing. A simple space at the end could cost you hours of debugging.

Comment: alert(response); giving values <h3>No Couriers found near by you.please select another location</h3>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, i suggest you to use status for ajax response something like:

```
1 for success
0 for failure
```

Than, as per your statement, your are getting the correct response in:

```
alert(response);
```

Than, you must need to check either response having `<h3></h3>` tags or not.

In your code, the main issue is that, you are using string without quotes in alert `alert(thanks);` this will return `undefined thanks` in console and treated as a variable.

This should be `alert("thanks");`

*One more suggestion, it's always better to check browser console when you are not getting success in Ajax or any other script, this will help you to find the errors.*

Comment: alert(response); giving  <h3>No Couriers found near by you.please select another location</h3>

Answer (score 1):

In your php script, return a boolean flag instead of a string :

```
<?php
if (some_condition) {
    $return = true;
} else {
    $return = false;
}
die(json_encode(array('return' => $return)));
```

And in the ajax success :

```
...
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
    if (data.return) {
        alert("return is true");
    } else {
        alert("return is false");
    }
},
...
```

Hope it helps.

PS : use Json Encode to parse the response and access values easily.